# ! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr in table with array

Tags: tables, arrays

This is the error I have gotten while having my table as here ;

```
 ! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
```

\endtemplate

l.168           Sample &
                  Size ( $\mu$ m) & Main mineral phases \

```
\begin{table}
    \caption[]{Main composition of the studied regolith samples}
        \label{Tab1}
        $$
        \begin{array}{p{0.5\linewidth}}
            \hline
            \noalign{\smallskip}
            Sample & Size ( $\mu$ m) & Main mineral phases \\
            \noalign{\smallskip}
            \hline
            \noalign{\smallskip}
                RA-QD02-0014 & 131.2 $ \pm$ 0.1 & Olivine, low-Ca pyroxene, plagioclase \\
                RA-QD02-0023 & 149.4 $ \pm$ 0.1 & Olivine, troilite \\
                RA-QD02-0047 & 108.0 $ \pm$ 0.1 & Olivine, low-Ca and high-Ca pyroxene \\
            \noalign{\smallskip}
            \hline
        \end{array}
            $$
\end{table}
```

Comment: You've defined the `array` environment with a single column (of type `p`), yet you then proceed to populate it with 3 rows, each containing 3 columns.

Comment: How should I define 3 columns?

Comment: `\begin{array}{p{0.25\linewidth}p{0.25\linewidth}p{0.25\linewidth}` will define 3 columns, of course narrower than one huge one.

Comment: Where did you get the code from to begin with? It is quite strange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you've defined the `array` environment to have a single column, yet the tabular material has three columms.

Using an `array` environment for the material at hand isn't all that convenient, as only one of the three columns contains anything math-y. It would be better to use a `tabular` environment. Also, using lots of `\noalign{\smallskip}` instances is cumbersome; it's preferable to load the `booktabs` package and employ its macros `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` to generate well-spaced horizontal lines. A separate comment: To typeset scientific units such as "micro-meters", consider loading the `siunitx` package and employing that package's `\si` macro.

Here's how I would display the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}  % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}} % automatic math mode, centering
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, % '\toprule', '\midrule', etc.
            amsmath,  % for '\text'  macro
            siunitx}  % for '\si' macro

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \caption{Main composition of the studied regolith samples}
    \label{Tab1}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{} lCl @{}} % middle column is in math mode automatically
    \toprule
    Sample & \text{Size (\si{\micro\meter})} & Main mineral phases \\
    \midrule
    RA-QD02-0014 & 131.2 \pm 0.1 & Olivine, low-Ca pyroxene, plagioclase \\
    RA-QD02-0023 & 149.4 \pm 0.1 & Olivine, troilite \\
    RA-QD02-0047 & 108.0 \pm 0.1 & Olivine, low-Ca and high-Ca pyroxene \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

---

*Addendum to address the OP's follow-up questions:

- Keep captions short and snappy. If the table requires a legend, don't place the legend inside the argument of `\caption`.
- If your table has 7 columns (1 header column and 6 data columns), you need to provide 7, not 6, column specifiers.
- For improved legibility of the tabular material, consider placing the units of measurement in a separate row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % choose suitable page parameters
\usepackage{array}  % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}} 
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, % '\toprule', '\midrule', etc.
            amsmath,  % for '\text'  macro
            siunitx}  % for '\si' macro
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Average mechanical properties of Itokawa regolith silicates in particles of given S\#.} 
%% keep captions short and snappy!
\label{Tab2}

Reduced Young's modulus ($E_r$), hardness ($H$), constant stiffness ($S$), elastic recovery ($U_{\mathrm{el}}/ U_{\mathrm{tot}}$) and plasticity index ($U_{\mathrm{pl}}/ U_{\mathrm{tot}}$) were calculated by averaging the results from two lines of indentations from the maximum applied force of \SI{10}{\milli\newton}.

\medskip
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l CCCCCC @{}}
\toprule 
Sample 
& \text{Applied Force} & E_{r} & H & S 
& U_{\mathrm{el}}/ U_{\mathrm{tot}} 
& U_{\mathrm{pl}}/ U_{\mathrm{tot}}\\ 
& (\si{\milli\newton}) 
& (\si{\giga\pascal})
& (\si{\giga\pascal}) 
& (\si{\milli\newton\per\micro\meter})\\ % micron = micro-meter ??
\midrule
RA-QD02-0014 
& \cdots & \cdots & \cdots 
& \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. That works now. I try it for the next table, but I get some errors.

Comment: Thos it work for six coloumns?

Comment: \begin{tabular}{@{} l @{}    l Cl @{} l @{}  l C l  C   } % middle column is in math mode automatically
    \toprule
            Sample     &  Applied Force (mN) & E_{r} (GPa)  & H (GPa) & S (mN/ micron) & U_{el}/ U_{tot}  & U_{pl}/ U_{tot}\\

Comment: @Yasamin - Your example seems to have 7 columns, not 6.

Comment: I put: \begin{tabular}{C l C   l Cl C l C  l C   }  . and I get this error: ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \@currentlabelname.

Comment: Is there anything wrong in my caption:     \caption{Average mechanical properties of Itokawa regolith silicates in particles of given S$\#$. Reduced Young´s modulus (Er), hardness (H), constant stiffness (S), elastic recovery (U$\_{el}$/U$\_{tot}$) and plasticity index (U$\_{pl}$/U$\_{tot}$) were calculated by averaging the results from two lines of indentations from the maximum applied force of 10 mN.}

Comment: @Yasamin - "Is there anything wrong with my caption?" Yes! Several things, in fact. Please see the addendum I just posted.